# Make Bootstrap style to override woocommerce-layout?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, overriding

When bootstrap.min.css below woocommerce-layout.css (image 1), however, the style of woocommerce-layout still overrided (image 2) class of bootstrap (.col-lg-2, .col-xs-6... etc).

So how can I do to override bootstrap style over woocommerce style?

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Comment: Added the images from the OP's links.

Answer (score 0):

Make the selectors in the last loading CSS file more exact, or add !important to the declarations in that file.

Comment: Both bootstrap and woocommerce-layout are external library and I don't want to modify them

Answer (score 0):

OK, then add a new stylesheet after they have both loaded. Then copy the selectors you want to change to that sheet and add !important declarations (or make them more specific)